# Uploading multipart file in spring mvc which is protected with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, multipart

```
I am trying to upload the MultiPart file in spring mvc rest services with the application secured with spring security.
The problem is I am able to upload the file succesfully but the uploaded file is corrupted(Not able to open that file),This happens only If I secured the application with spring security.

Here is the web.xml
```

> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
>
> ```
>   <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
>       and Filters -->
>   <context-param>
>       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>       <param-value>
>                   /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml 
>                   /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-config.xml
>                   /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/mail-config.xml
>       </param-value>
>   </context-param>
>
>   <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
>   <listener>
>       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
>   </listener>
>
>   <!-- Processes application requests -->
>   <servlet>
>       <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
>       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>       <init-param>
>           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>           <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
>       </init-param>
>       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
>   </servlet>
>   <!-- Spring Security filter <filter> <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
>       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
>
>       </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
>       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> -->
>
>
>   <filter>
>       <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
>       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
>   </filter>
>   <filter>
>       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
>   </filter>
>   <filter-mapping>
>       <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
>       <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
>   </filter-mapping>
>   <filter-mapping>
>       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
>       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>       <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
>       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
>       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
>   </filter-mapping>
>
>   </web-app>
> ```

```
Below is the code on the server side to accept the file
```

> package com.upload.controller;
>   This is the sample code that I am using in the spring mvc controller to upload the files to server now I am using in my local host
>
> ```
> import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.List;
> import java.nio.file.Files;
> import java.nio.file.Paths;
>
> import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
> import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
>
> import org.slf4j.Logger;
> import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
> import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
> import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
> import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
> import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
> import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
>
> //import com.journaldev.spring.controller.FileUploadController;
>
> @RestController
> @RequestMapping("/upload")
> // @MultipartConfig(maxFileSize=5242880,maxRequestSize=20971520,location="/home/java-root/Desktop/temp",fileSizeThreshold=0)
> public class FileUploadController {
>   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
>           .getLogger(FileUploadController.class);
>
>   // private static String UPLOAD_LOCATION = "/home/java-root/Desktop/temp/";
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>   public @ResponseBody
>   String multiFileUpload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file,
>           HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
>       List<MultipartFile> files = Arrays.asList(file);
>
>       List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
>       String UPLOAD_LOCATION = "/home/java-root/Desktop/temp/";
>
>       if (null != files && files.size() > 0) {
>           for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {
>
>               String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
>               Files.copy(
>                       multipartFile.getInputStream(),
>                       Paths.get(UPLOAD_LOCATION,
>                               multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
>               // Files.co
>               fileNames.add(fileName);
>               // Handle file content - multipartFile.getInputStream()
>
>           }
>       }
>       return "successfull";
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What does your security configuration look like? What are your logs? What version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: This is the last few lines of logs that I got when I run in DEBUG Mode

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="restAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <http security="none" pattern="/api/webhook" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/api/productsearch" />
    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/customers/guests" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/customers/feedback" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/customers/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <custom-filter ref="restSecurityFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="restSecurityFilter"
        class="com.condivision.rentongo.security.RestSecurityFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="authenticationManager"
            ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score -1):

2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:242 - Authorization successful
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:255 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:309 - /api/upload/data reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/rentongo/api/upload/data]
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG CommonsMultipartResolver:259 - Found multipart file [files] of size 73127 bytes with original filename [push20not.png], stored at [/home/java-root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/work/Catalina/localhost/rentongo/upload_71d6394a_142f_4765_8930_d7dc9c612c8d_00000000.tmp]
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:294 - Looking up handler method for path /upload/data
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:299 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.condivision.rentongo.controller.FileUploadController.multiFileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException]
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fileUploadController'
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:163 - Written [successfull] as "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@574040c1]
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG CommonsMultipartResolver:282 - Cleaning up multipart file [files] with original filename [push20not.png], stored at [/home/java-root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.67/work/Catalina/localhost/rentongo/upload_71d6394a_142f_4765_8930_d7dc9c612c8d_00000000.tmp]
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:996 - Successfully completed request
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:116 - Chain processed normally
2016-07-12 11:47:47 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: This are the versions

Comment: <properties>
  <java-version>1.7</java-version>
  <springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</springframework-version>
  <spring-security-version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
  <hibernate-version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate-version>
  <mysql-connector-java-version>5.1.35</mysql-connector-java-version>
  <jackson-version>2.5.4</jackson-version>
  <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
 </properties>

Comment: add this in question comment, not in answers